# while loop condition doesn't terminate when reading file is finished

Tags: c

this program will keep reading next 20 lines until **user enters 'q'** or **file reading is finished**.

now for **file reading is finished** part, I've condition on line 29 of this program  `flag != NULL`

as per my understanding fgets() returns NULL after it reach EOF but this condition doesn't work. what can I do to stop the loop after file has been read?

I'm using [this file](https://gist.github.com/ganganimaulik/940198fd379c8a37ecc16b9d28425097) for testing and here's my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char name[66];
    printf("Enter name of  file: ");
    scanf("%65s", name);

    FILE *fp = fopen(name, "r");

    if (!fp) {
        printf("can't open file for reading\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int  i = 1;

    char buffer1[1000];
    char *flag;
    char c;

    do {
        do {
            i++;
            flag = fgets(buffer1, 999, fp);
            printf("%s", buffer1);
            //printf("%d***\n", i);  //debug - print line number
        } while (i % 20 != 0 && flag != NULL);
        scanf(" %c", &c);
    } while (c != 'q');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: isn't scanf blocking... meaning it will actually pause each 20 until the user reacts

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. scanf will ask user input after each 20 lines.

Comment: Sidenote: `flag`s are typically boolean values, not pointers. Using moire appropriate names makes code much more clear and help spotting logical errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your outer `do-while` loop won't terminate until the user enters `q` even when EOF is reached.

```
do {
    do {
        i++;
        flag = fgets(buffer1, 999, fp);
        printf("%s", buffer1);
        //printf("%d***\n", i);  //debug - print line number
    } while (i % 20 != 0 && flag != NULL);
    scanf(" %c", &c);
} while (c != 'q'); // no EOF checking here
```

This will probably do what you want:

```
do {
    do {
        i++;
        flag = fgets(buffer1, 999, fp);
        // only print if fgets() returned new data
        if (flag != NULL) {
            printf("%s", buffer1);
        }
        //printf("%d***\n", i);  //debug - print line number
    } while (i % 20 != 0 && flag != NULL);
    scanf(" %c", &c);
} while (c != 'q' && flag != NULL);
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ganganimaulik/951ec5cbf0fb109b06de893d5742ee3a 

I've done this and it solves the issue but last line gets printed twice :o

Comment: @MaulikGangani *last line gets printed twice*  That's because you call `printf()` even if your call to `fgets()` fails and returns `NULL`.  See my edit

Comment: Note:  `1000-1` not needed in `char buffer1[1000]; ... fgets(buffer1, 999, fp);`  Better to use 1000 via `fgets(buffer1, sizeof buffer, fp);`.

Comment: @chux Those would be improvements, but I decided to not make such changes and just make changes relevant to the question.  I also considered the additional parenthesis used in the other answer, but again, I tried to stay close to the original posted code. (I became a big fan of parenthesizing everything when I spent close to a week trying to run down a bug that I finally traced to a huge conditional clause that omitted such parenthesis...)

Answer (score 2):

You are not exiting the outer loop. In the outer while loop change

```
while (c != 'q');
```

to

```
while ((c != 'q') && (flag !=NULL));
```